# MS Sql Server - Clustered index requirement when changing filegroup of table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-administration, filegroup

Can someone explain to me the reason a clustered index is required on Sql Server tables when moving them to another file group.

A table without a clustered index is stored as a heap where as adding a clustered index would change it to a B-Tree. Both heap and B Tree are tree-based data structures differing in the fact that B Tree is ordered. Why would this influence a table's file group changes?

Asking more out of curiosity rather than facing a active problem..Thanks

Comment: A heap isn't a tree structure. It is just a bunch of leaves. But I'm not sure why whether it is a tree would be relevant to this anyway. I imagine it is probably because if the table has non clustered indexes they are more problematic for a heap as they contain the physical rid (coupled to the original physical location) not a logical key

Comment: Thanks martin. I meant 'Tree based' data structure. corrected.